# Runtime Initialization in Swift

Tags: swift

I am currently trying to implement a method that will allow me to initialize new instances of a class during runtime.(Such as simply adding a new person to a contact list.) Much searching eventually led me to Object Factories,  yet a closer look merely presented arguments stating that they were unnecessary in Swift.

Here I am simply trying to initialize a new instance of Person then immediately append said Person to the People array with a function that can be later tied to user input.

```
 class Person{
     var name: String
     var age: Int
     init(name: String, age: Int){
         self.name = name
         self.age = age
     }
 }

 var People:[Person] = []

 func CreatePerson () {
   // here I would be creating an instance of Person initialized with name and age
   // People.append (just made Person).
 }
```

Comment: All initialization is "runtime"... what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If I had to make a guess, I'm thinking you're looking to pick between one of several types to instantiate and use polymorphically. Is this correct?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work with `Person(name: "confusedCoder90", age: 26)`?

Answer (score 0):

In the `MainClass` you create an `arrayOfPersons` where Persons will be stored. Then in the function you append the new Person to the array providing the name and the age. Remember to call self.createPerson() somewhere to make it work. My suggestion is to start testing it in the `viewDidLoad`.

```
class Person {
var name: String
var age: Int
init(name: String, age: Int){
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
}}

class MainClass { 
    var arrayOfPersons = [Person]();

    func createPerson () {
        let newPersonName = "Name and Surname";
        let newPersonAge = 18;
        let newPerson = Person(name: newPersonName, age: newPersonAge);
        self.arrayOfPersons.append(newPerson);
    }
}
```

To check that it was added well you can print the array calling the `self.printArray();` after `self.createPerson();`:

```
func printArray() {
    for person in arrayOfPersons {
        print("Person Name: \(person.name), \(person.age)");
    }
}
```